# Table Data expanding in New Tab

Tags: javascript, database, firebase-realtime-database, html-table, datatables

So I'm working on a a database website which allows the user to insert data of registered visitors this includes their name, DOB, address, Gender, and more about their medical conditions. Now I am using Firebase Realtime Database to save the data and also snapshot the value in a table where specific information of the visiter can be seen.

What I now want is to make each row that is being append and added to be clickable and when it is clicked it opens in a new tab that has the complete data of the specific visitor. The data in the new tab should also be retrieved from Firebase.

But I am unsure about how I can do this and require help.

Please let me know if there is a need of any further details.

Comment: Please include code in your post and what you've achieved so far and what you've tried doing. Don't expect people to recreate your code for you to present the solution.

Comment: If you can assist I can connect personally with you to provide you with the codes as I have multiple files that will work concurrently to make possible the action I want to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use ejs for rendering that information

by using ejs you can pass on variables to the webpage when it is loaded

**Example**

```
app.post("/signin",function(req,res){
var user = new User({
    username:req.body.username,
    password:req.body.password
});
 req.login(user,function(err){
    passport.authenticate("local",{failureRedirect:"/signinERR"})(req,res,function(){
        res.render("/",{username:req.body.username});
    });
});
});
```

and in ejs file you can access the username variable like this

```
<h1>Welcome <%= username %> </h1>
```

read more about ejs here https://ejs.co/